# Getting 400 response error code when running query with apollo/react-hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

My dependencies are:

```
"@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.1",
"apollo-boost": "^0.4.4",
"graphql": "^14.5.6",
"react": "^16.9.0",
```

My query calling React component is:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';

const FEED_QUERY = gql`
  {
    session(session_id: $id) {
      session_id
      event_type
    }
  }
`

function SessionDetails() {
  const id = "web123";
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(FEED_QUERY, {
    variables: { id },
  });
  console.log(error)
  console.log(data)

  if (loading) return <div>Fetching</div>
  if (error) return <div>Error</div>

  const sessionsToRender = data.session

  return (
    <div>
      {sessionsToRender.map(session => <Session key={session.session_id} session={session} />)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I am getting `error` as `"Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400"` and my data is `undefined`. The query is working properly in the GraphQL playground but not in the app. It seems that id is not being replaced. How do I fix it?

[image: From Google Dev Console]

Comment: The query is working in there but it not working here.

Comment: @HMR I got `Variable "$id" is not defined` from graphiql.

Comment: @HMR I managed to do what you asked. From my web app, the id field is not being replaced while in graphql because I am sending a constant value it is being sent properly.

Comment: @HMR I have done that.

Comment: Duplicate of [GraphQl variable using grapiql - variable is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54293234/graphql-variable-using-grapiql-variable-is-undefined)

Comment: Any variable you use must first be declared as part of your operation definition. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54293234/graphql-variable-using-grapiql-variable-is-undefined).

Comment: @DanielRearden I did what that answer said to do and it solved that problem. But then another error message pooped up `Variable "$id" of type "String" used in position expecting type "String!`. Only removing `!` from `String`, it worked. Why was this problem occurring even though I gave an actual id and not a blank one?

Comment: if he field is nullable, the variable can be nullable or non-nullable. If the field is non-nullable, the variable must be too.

Comment: @DanielRearden How do I make a variable in JS non-nullable?

Comment: The same way you make a field non-nullable in SDL -- by appending the `!` to the type.

Comment: @DanielRearden Ah, I got it. You meant in the gql. I thought you meant in JS.